# Finding the commutator of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Consider the group $G = \langle a, b : a^{11} = 1, b^{10} = 1, ba = a^6
b\rangle$.

Find $[a,b]$.

I know $[a,b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ but don't know where to go from here.

I think one type could be $[a^i,a^j]=a^ia^ja^{-i}a^{-j}=1$? But can't quite see others

Comment: Rewrite the relation in the form $bab^{-1} = a^6$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$aba^{-1}b^{-1}=ab(ba)^{-1}=ab(a^6b)^{-1}=abb^{-1}a^{-6}=a^{-5}=a^6$

Comment: Thank you, this really helps. Just one thing, how does $a^{-5}=a^6$?

Comment: Thats because $a^{11}=1$ i.e. $a^6.a^5=1\Rightarrow a^6=a^{-5}$ by definition of inverse elements.