# Finding the derived group of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Consider the group $G = \langle a, b : a^{11} = 1, b^{10} = 1, ba = a^6
b\rangle$.
The commutator of $a$ and $b$, $[a,b]=a^6$

Show that $[g, h] \in \langle a\rangle$ for all $g, h ∈ G$, and hence find $G'$.

So if $[a,b]=a^6$ then $[g, h]=g^6$? but cannot see how to show $g^6$ $\in\langle a\rangle$.. or how we can use this to find $G'$

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211620/finding-the-commutator-of-a-group) for the earlier question.

Comment: $G/\langle a \rangle$ is a cyclic group generated by the image of $b$, so it is abelian. Hence $G' \le \langle a \rangle$, and so $[g,h] \in G' \le \langle a \rangle$ for all $g,h \in G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Because of $ba=a^6b$ we see that all elements of $G$ are of the form $a^ib^j$, so that
$$
G=\{a^ib^j\mid 0\le i\le 10,0\le j\le 9\}
$$
is a non-abelian group with $110$ elements (a non-trivial semidirect product with cyclic factors $C_2,C_5,C_{11}$). Now we could compute all commutators $[a^ib^j,a^kb^l]$ directly. We already know that $[a^1b^0,a^0b^1]=[a,b]=a^6$.

Comment: So $[g, h]\in\langle a\rangle $ because $g^6$ is of the form $a^ib^j$ where $i=6$ and $j=0$?

Comment: No, $g=a^ib^j$ and $h=a^kb^l$. Then why should $[g,h]$  be in $\langle a\rangle$?

Comment: I am told $[g,h]$ is in $\langle a \rangle$ but need to show that it is. So $[g,h]=[a^ib^j,a^kb^l]=a^ib^ja^kb^l(a^ib^j)^{-1}(a^kb^l)^{-1}=a^ib^ja^kb^lb^{-j}a^{-i}b^{-l}a^{-k}$.. not sure quite where to go from here though

Comment: Now interchange all $a$'s and $b$'s according to the rule $ba=a^6b$, until you are back to the form $a^ib^j$. Claim: then $j=0$.

Comment: Okay thank you so should I end up with $a^{-215i-1290k}$ which is in $\langle a \rangle$?

Comment: Yes, we will indeed end up in $\langle a \rangle$. Of course, the argument that $G/\langle a\rangle$ is cyclic is more elegant. There are $5$ different non-abelian groups of order $110$, and we have determined which one this is.

Comment: So since $G/\langle a \rangle$ is cyclic it is also abelian and therefore $G'\leq\langle a \rangle$. So $G'$ could $ = \langle a\rangle\cong C_{11} $, right? But  how do I know this is the _smallest_ normal subgroup with abelian quotient?

Comment: There is no smaller subgroup of $C_{11}=\{e,a,a^2,\ldots ,a^{10}\}$, if $a$ is in there.